# Batch-delete route stops from an existing route?

Tags: maximo

In Maximo 7.6.1.1:

Is there a way to batch-delete route stops from an existing route?

- Delete all route stops from a route
- Delete route stops from a route that meet certain criteria (filter, advanced query, or WHERE clause)

Note:

I have thousands of route stops per route. The solution needs to delete all route stops that apply -- not just the route stops that appear in the first page of the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An automation script can do this.

1. Create a Sig Option in the Routes application with Advanced property "for use by user in the UI".
2. Add the Sig Option to the Select Action menu or drop a pushbutton on the main tab of Routes with an event equal to the Sig Option name -- so a user with permission can see and click the Sig Option.
3. If desired, use selection columns from other apps to add one to Routes.
4. Grant the Sig Option to appropriate Security Groups.
5. Create an autoscript with an Action launch point against the routes object, and *name the Action the same as the Sig Option*. You could make the script look for `routeStopMbo.isSelected()` or just cycle through all the Mbos in the `routeStopSet` on the assumption that they have survived the user's filter.